# Inject a javascript value into datalayer key value

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer, enhanced-ecommerce

I'm trying to add an event ID to my website pages (WordPress site) so I can use it to generate an "event ID" for Enhanced eCommerce events that I push to google tag manager to avoid the same event being counted twice from the server and browser to GA4 and facebook.

I'm using the function

```
function event_id() {
eturn 'xxxxxxxx.xxxx.4xxx.yxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
return v.toString(16);
});
```

to generate a unique ID, after that, I want to inject its value in the 'event id' as you can see below :

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({
'event': 'page_id',
'event_id': 'event_id'
};
```

please some help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a Community Template which generates an event ID as a variable for you: https://tagmanager.google.com/gallery/#/owners/stape-io/templates/unique-event-id-variable

This way it's not in the `dataLayer` but as a variable which you can then access in your other tags, e.g. facebook/meta.

Comment: every time you access the variable it send a new ID so it's not the solution, the ID must be stocked in the data layer so multiple tag can use it

Comment: Variables are evaluated once for each event. Therefore, each tag firing on the same event will access the same random event ID.